# Ajax Form Submitting two times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="position:relative">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Add New Video
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" id="VideoAdd" action="process_VideoAdd.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="alert" style="display:none;" id="videoError">

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                        </span> 
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Video Url" name="vurl" id="vurl" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" value="Update">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
</div>
```

Php code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require("include/inc.php");
    require("include/class/class.admin.php");

$admin=New adminClass($db);
if (!$admin->LoggedIn())
{
    echo "error_redirect";
}else
{

    if($_POST["vurl"])
    {
        if($admin->AddVideo($_POST["vurl"]))
        {
            echo "success";

        }else{
            echo "Error in updating";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

js code

```
$("#VideoAdd").submit(function(e)
    {

        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $("#videoError").hide();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                if(data=="error_redirect")
                {
                    window.location="login.php";

                }else if(data=="success"){
                    $("#videoError").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#videoError").show();
                    $("#videoError").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#videoError").html("Successfully Updated");
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#videoError").show();
                    $("#videoError").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#videoError").html("Error in updating");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {

            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

    });
```

This is my code for submitting url value through ajax. it works well when using in local host(wamp server). But when I upload this code to my webserver and run it, it always submitted two times into the database when click on the submit button.

Comment: Can you check console how many post calls going.

Comment: What if you move `e.preventDefault()` to the top?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

use js as:-
// disable this button
// take button id as 

// disable add button

```
var is_request_sent = false; // declare global var for request
$("#VideoAdd").submit(function(e)
    {
        if(is_request_sent == false)
        {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $("#videoError").hide();

            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    if(data=="error_redirect")
                    {
                        window.location="login.php";

                    }else if(data=="success"){
                        $("#videoError").removeClass("alert-danger");
                        $("#videoError").show();
                        $("#videoError").addClass("alert-success");
                        $("#videoError").html("Successfully Updated");
                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#videoError").show();
                        $("#videoError").addClass("alert-danger");
                        $("#videoError").html("Error in updating");
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    is_request_sent = false;
                    $('#submit_form').removeAtrr('disabled');
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                     // Handle the beforeSend event 
                     is_request_sent = true;
                      $('#submit_form').atrr('disabled','disabled');
                },
                complete: function(){
                 // Handle the complete event
                 is_request_sent = false;
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your HTML code and a bit js change as well. e.preventDefault(); is not working your code because submit is a function not an event.

Html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="position:relative">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Add New Video
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <form role="form" id="VideoAdd">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="alert" style="display:none;" id="videoError">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                                                </span> 
                                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Video Url" name="vurl" id="vurl" type="text" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="submit" id="videoSbmt" class="btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" value="Update">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                                <!-- /.panel-body -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.panel -->
                        </div>
```

js code

```
$("#videoSbmt").click(function(e)
    {

        var postData = $("#videoAdd").serializeArray();
        var formURL = "process_VideoAdd.php";
        $("#videoError").hide();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                if(data=="error_redirect")
                {
                    window.location="login.php";

                }else if(data=="success"){
                    $("#videoError").removeClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#videoError").show();
                    $("#videoError").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#videoError").html("Successfully Updated");
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#videoError").show();
                    $("#videoError").addClass("alert-danger");
                    $("#videoError").html("Error in updating");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {

            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action` should be the first thing you do, not the last. Remember the `$.ajax()` call is asyncronous, so while that is running the default action is probably being run.

```
$("#VideoAdd").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $("#videoError").hide();

    $.ajax({
       url : formURL,
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       data : postData,
       success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if(data=="error_redirect") {
             window.location="login.php";
          }else if(data=="success"){
              $("#videoError").removeClass("alert-danger");
              $("#videoError").show();
              $("#videoError").addClass("alert-success");
              $("#videoError").html("Successfully Updated");
          } else {
              alert(data);
              $("#videoError").show();
              $("#videoError").addClass("alert-danger");
              $("#videoError").html("Error in updating");
          }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using .one(),

```
$("#VideoAdd").one('submit'. function(e){

...
});
```